# Android Service instance continue to exist after onDestroy() and GC

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, leakcanary

I have created a test app to see if Android's Service is being recycled properly.

I created a Service that does one thing: holding a WeakReference to a object. The idea is, after the Service is destroyed and GC is called, the WeakReference should return null. Here is my Service:

```
package com.example.test.serviceleaktest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;


public class MyService extends Service {

    public static WeakReference sWeakReference = new WeakReference(null);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        sWeakReference = new WeakReference("data");
        Log.d("asdf", "MyService started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("asdf", "MyService created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("asdf", "MyService destroyed");
    }

}
```

I start the Service using Context.startService() and stop it using Context.stopService(). LogCat confirms onDestroy() is called. Then I do a GC(code copied from LeakCanary):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
Thread.sleep(100);
System.runFinalization();
```

At this point, I assume sWeakReference.get() should return null, right? But it's still returning the assigned value. Why?

Comment: I believe there is an implicit hard reference to the string literal `"data"` via `sWeakReference = new WeakReference("data")`. Try `sWeakReference = new WeakReference(new String("data"))` instead. What is the intent of having the weak ref to the string by the way?

Comment: Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is, after the Service is destroyed and GC is called, the WeakReference should return null.

You seem to misunderstand `WeakReference`s, or at least it's not evident to me why you think the code you presented demonstrates any unexpected behavior.  If you create a `WeakReference` to some object `o`, and some time later the GC determines that `o` is not strongly reachable, then the GC will clear the `WeakReference`.

You are creating a `WeakReference` to a `String` object, represented in your source code as a literal.  If Java uses the intern version of that `String` -- which it quite likely will do -- then it may choose to treat it as always strongly reachable, so that the reference object is never cleared.

Inasmuch as you say you want to monitor the cleanup of a `Service`, and you present a subclass of `Service`, I'm inclined to think that you suppose you are monitoring cleanup of the object that *created* the `WeakReference`.  That's not the way it works.

If indeed you want to monitor cleanup of the `Service`, then you want to create a `WeakReference` *to the service object*.  In your current code, that would be spelled `new WeakReference(this)`.

Note also that monitoring when an object ceases to be strongly reachable is the purpose of `ReferenceQueue`s.  If you create a `ReferenceQueue` and register your `WeakReference` with it, then you can watch for the weak reference to be enqueued instead of testing whether its target is cleared.